# Como dar alertas a un botón dependiendo si su estado es true o false mediante funciones

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, funciones, condiciones

soy nuevo en este mundillo y tengo una duda con la que llevo peleando varios días.

En mi código tengo un **botón** que gracias a la función de **JS** en **HTML**:

```
function comprobarInfoEquipo(obj) {
    if (obj.checked)
        document.getElementById('btnperfil').disabled = false;
    else
        document.getElementById('btnperfil').disabled = true;
}
```

detecta si en un formulario quedan campos por introducir, desactive el botón(**False**), y si están todos rellenos lo active(**True**).

Mi problema es que quiero que cuando el botón esté desactivado mande una `<alert>` indicando que faltan campos, y que cuando el botón este activado mande otra `<alert>` distinta diciendo que el usuario se creo correctamente.

Hasta ahora solo he conseguido que pulsando el boton independientemente de su estado mande la misma alerta siempre, he probado `callbacks` sin mucho éxito e incluso haciendo una función para **true** y otra para **false** e incluyéndole ambas al mismo botón y otra vez sin mucho éxito.

Desconozco si hay alguna función que me permita hacer eso o meter algo dentro del `if` y `else` que se base en el estado(**true y false**).

Muchísimas gracias.

---

@kyara, pff he intentado modificar el código y nada, solo salta la primera función:

```
function valida_envia() {
    //valido el nombre
    if (document.registro.nombre.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre")
        document.fvalida.nombre.focus()
        return 0;
    }

    //valido la fecha
    if (document.registro.fecha.selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert("Seleccione fecha de nacimiento")
        document.fvalida.fecha.focus()
        return 0;
    }
    //valido el mail
    if (document.registro.correo.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Tiene que escribir su Correo Electrónico")
        document.fvalida.correo.focus()
        return 0;
    }
    //valido la contraseña
    if (document.registro.contraseña.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Tiene que escribir su Contraseña")
        document.fvalida.contraseña.focus()
        return 0;
    }
    //valido el usuario
    if (document.registro.usuario.value.length == 0) {
        alert("Tiene que escribir su nombre de usuario")
        document.fvalida.usuario.focus()
        return 0;
    }
    //valido el servidor
    if (document.registro.servidor.selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert("Debe seleccionar un servidor")
        document.registro.servidor.focus()
        return 0;
    }

    //el formulario se envia
    alert("Muchas gracias por enviar el formulario");
    document.registro.submit();
    }
```

el botón lo tenia con un `type=submit` y lo he cambiado a `type=button` como indicaba la pagina y no se envía el formulario

El **HTML** del formulario es este:

```
<form method="post" target="_self" name="registro">
        <table class="perfil">
            <tr class="perfil">
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Nombre y Apellidos</p><br>
                    <input class="caja" type="text" name="nombre" value="" required /><br>
                </td>
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Fecha de Nacimiento</p><br>
                    <input class="caja" type="date" name="fecha" required><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="perfil">
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Correo Electrónico</p><br>
                    <input class="caja" type="text" name="correo" value="" required /><br>
                </td>
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Contraseña (Entre 4 y 10 máx.)</p><br>
                    <input class="caja" type="password" name="contraseña" value="" minlength="4" maxleght="10"
                        required /><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="perfil">
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Usuario (Entre 8 y 10 máx.)</p><br>
                    <input class="caja" type="text" name="usuario" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="20" required /><br>
                </td>
                <td class="perfil">
                    <p class="texto">Alojamiento Servidor</p><br>
                    <select name="servidor" class="caja" required>
                        <option value="0" class="opcmenu">Elija una opción porfavor</option>
                        <optgroup label="Europa" class="grupserv"></optgroup>
                        <option value="1">España</option>
                        <option value="2">Francia</option>
                        <option value="3">Alemania</option>
                        <optgroup label="Asia" class="grupserv"></optgroup>
                        <option value="1">China</option>
                        <option value="2">Japón</option>
                        <option value="3">India</option>
                        <optgroup label="América" class="grupserv"></optgroup>
                        <option value="1">EE.UU</option>
                        <option value="2">Canadá</option>
                        <option value="3">México</option>
                    </select><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="perfil">
                <td class="perfil">
                    <input id="btnperfil" class="btnperfil" type="submit" value="Enviar" name="buscar"
                        onclick="valida_envia()">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade este código para la validación de la fecha:

```
 let isValidDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
       
    if (isNaN(isValidDate)) {
        alert("Seleccione fecha de nacimiento")
        document.fvalida.fecha.focus()
        return 0;
    }
```

con

```
document.getElementById("fecha").value
```

se recoge el valor del html donde hayas puesto el id fecha en este caso iría en el input de la fecha

```
<input class="caja" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required><br>
```

El Date.parse() valida la fecha de entrada. Si no la reconoce devolverá NaN (no un número) como salida. El resultado se guarda en isValidDate. Si es NaN devolverá false y entrará en el if.

Por otro lado, el servidor lo comprobé con tu código y si me salta la alerta

Comment: para la fecha me bastó con cambiar el if de `document.registro.fecha.selectIndex` a `document.registro.fecha.value` pero el servidor me sigue saltando la alerta pero acto seguido se envía todo el formulario sin dejarme elegir la opción, probé a cambiarle el **selectIndex** a **value** también y aun así, creo que será error del ultimo if

Comment: @Hugo_jim ya vi porque se envía el formulario igualmente. Necesitas cambiar el tipo botón que tienes. Actualmente lo tienes como `type: "submit"`. Tiene que ser `type="button"` para que llame a la función correctamente y valide todo el formulario antes de enviarlo.

Comment: me funcionó correctamente con el `type="button"`,muchisimas gracias, me has salvado de mi calvario :-)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner dentro del if una alerta después de activar el botón e igualmente en el else. Podría ser algo así:

```
function comprobarInfoEquipo(obj) {
if (obj.checked)
   document.getElementById('btnperfil').disabled = false;
   alert("Usuario creado correctamente");
else
   document.getElementById('btnperfil').disabled = true;
   alert("Faltan campos por rellenar");
}
```

También he visto que para mostrar el error se puede añadir debajo del formulario un div oculto:

```
<div class="form-errors"></div>

$(".form-errors").text("The form is not complete").show();
```

Te paso enlace dónde hablan de esto último. Espero te sirva de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142652/show-message-instead-of-alert

También te adjunto enlace de otra paǵina interesante dónde habla de los alert: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1767.php

Comment: Si la opción de meter la alerta debajo del if ya lo probé, pero el botón necesita otra función a la que llame `hizoClick` y habría que relacionarlas de alguna manera, ahora probare la segunda opción y los links, muchísimas gracias!!<3

Comment: El segundo link es un poco mas tosco ya que creas varias alertas pero me pondré a modificarlo y acabare con el resultado que busco, repitiéndome otra vez, mil gracias

Comment: De nada :) Espero que logres el resultado. Si quieres puedes mostrar más de tu código para ver como esta todo relacionado. @Hugo_jim

Comment: pff he intentado modificarlo y solo me salta la primera alerta, las demás no saltan

Comment: Muestra más tu código, el html y tu js para ver cómo funciona e intentar ayudarte

Comment: he creado una respuesta con el código

Comment: Te escribo aquí porque no tengo reputación para responder a tu respuesta. Cómo tienes puesto el campo de fecha en el formulario? Tal vez es porque tienes uno por defecto y por eso siempre hay una fecha. Si no puedes probar estas formas de verificar una fecha: https://blog.reaccionestudio.com/funciones-para-validar-fechas-con-javascript/ y lo del servidor como es? un select?. Si puedes modifica la respuesta anterior y pon tu html también

Comment: la fecha es un date que sale `dd/mm/aaaa y un iconito de calendario` es un` type=date` clásico y el de servidores es un `select` con grupos y subgrupos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso del required, desde el html, es decir, por dar un ejemplo, en este form:

```css
const form = document.getElementById("transactionForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.reset();
})
```

```html
 <form id="transactionForm">
<div class="date-field"><label for="fecha">Fecha</label> <input  required type="date" class="validate" id="fecha" name="fecha"></div>
 <div><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="boton" name="action">Solicitar</button></div>
</form>
```

Te produciría un input que te exigiría rellenarlo, si intentas presionar el botón, saldrá un globo de "por favor rellena este campo", saliendo desde el input, creo que sería mejor que un alert :)